# Query SQL Server from SPSS how to connect

Tags: sql-server-2008, odbc, driver, spss

I am at a total loss on how to do what I think is a fairly simple and standard task:

I am running SPSS 20 on Mac and want to connect to a SQL Server database on a remote server.

When going to `File -> Open Database -> New Query` (The command names may be a bit off, my SPSS is in German and I'm just translating) it only shows myodbc as data source. I assume I have to add a driver for SQL Server however I don´t really know where to get it or how to install it as I cannot find it in the SPSS installation at hand. Anyone can help me out?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I am not a Mac user, but just by Googling I found this: http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbadmin/connect-s-3731160.html Maybe it helps.

Comment: I second djhurio's answer. I'm not a mac user either, but on Windows 7 I am connecting to a database using a system DSN, i.e. an ODBC connection. So if you set up your ODBC properly, you might need drivers for that, that's correct, you should be able to see this data source in SPSS.

Answer (score 0):

The Data Access Pack is available with your Statistics installation (may be a separate download), and it contains drivers for most major data sources.

Comment: I thought the same, that it should be somewhere but could not find anything. How would it be labeled? My download (from my institutions distribution system) contains only two folders, one of which has the installer. No separate files that could be drivers however. Would there be a way to get this pack later from IBM directly?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like IBM doesn't include (or make!) the drivers for Mac installations. Check it out:

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21480987

You have to buy them separately. For example:

- http://www.actualtech.com/download.php