# connect SQL to SPSS

Tags: sql, spss

I have table in Microsoft SQL server; and I'm using SPSS 14.1.
Now I want to connect SQL table to SPSS, so I can use SQL table from SPSS directly.

In SPSS, SQL database -> Data source -> Add New database connection -> Then I have 3 data source options only: dBASE Files, Excel Files, and MS Access Database. Which one can connect to SQL server?

Comment: It sounds like you need to add the server in the database connection wizard. After opening up the database wizard `Add ODBC Data Source -> Then under one of the "? DSN" pages click on Add, then add your SQL server.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query SQL Server from SPSS how to connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561968/query-sql-server-from-spss-how-to-connect)

Answer (score 2):

You should open the Microsoft ODBC Administrator from Start or the Control Panel. There you should activate the System SDN tab, click Add... and add a SQL Server data source.

A wizard will open, where you can enter the details. First the name of the connection, which will be used as a reference by SPSS. Then optionally a description, and the ip address or name of the server.

On the next page select the authentication method, and if needed, enter the user and password. From this point, the default settings will most likely be good. If you will have character coding problems or something like that, you may need to change these settings.

I also use ODBC connection to connect to the database from SPSS, and it works well.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You may need an ODBC driver from MS or use one from the Data Access Pack for SPSS, but you will need a driver specifically for SQL Server.